# Can someone help break down pointers in this code?

Tags: pointers

So this is my current code to divide using the subtraction method.

```
void int_div(unsigned int n, unsigned int d, unsigned int* q, unsigned int* r)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    *q = i;
    *r = n;
    for(n ; n >= 0 ; n = n - d)
        {
            if(n < d)
            {
                *r = n;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
               (*q)++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call the function, it looks something like (int_div 5, 2, &q, &r).

So I'm confused on when you are calling the function. So it's already been declared that q and r are pointers. But then how does

```
*q = i;
```

force that pointer to i rather than changing q to 0? I tried

```
q = &i;
```

and my output was dramatically different. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`q` is a `unsigned int` pointer, so `*q` will give you the value that this pointer points to. Hence doing `*q = i` means that you assign the value of the memory pointed by `q` to the value of `i`. As an example, if `i` = 3, then now the value pointed by `q` will be `3`.

If you do `q = &i`, then you reassign `q` to point to the address of variable `i`, which is a completely different operation.

Please read carefully C/C++ pointers and their `*` and `&` operations again :)